# Show another text on hover current text

Tags: html, css

I have text like below in my bootstrap 5. I am trying to show the English version of the text on hover current Gujarati text.

My HTML code is like below

```
<div class="blog_content d-flex flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3">
  <h5>નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની શરૂઆત </h5>
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0 quote-area">
    <div class="main-quote w-100">
      <p class="">નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની <br> શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય, <br> તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય, <br> આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ <br> પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક <br> શુભકામનાઓ !! </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlayTop">
      <p class="">nutan varsh 2023 ni <br> sharuat kaik evi thay, <br> tamar jivanam khushio felay, <br> anand mangalathi darek divas <br> pasar thay evi hardik <br> shubhakamanao !! </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto border-top pt-3">
    <div class="left text-start">
      <h6 class="mb-0">
        <a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.mysite.com/gu/festival/happy-new-year-2023">નવા વરસની શુભકામનાઓ</a>
      </h6>
      <p class="mb-0">
        <small>14 hours ago</small>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <a href="https://stag.mysite.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400">
        <img src="https://stag.mysite.com/assets/images/share.png" class="mx-2" alt="share quote" width="24" height="24">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I have applied styles like below

```
.quote-area {
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .overlayTop {
             position:absolute;
             transition:.5s ease;
             width:100%;
             background:#000;
             opacity:0;
             color:#fff;

        }
        
        .main-quote:hover .overlayTop {
            opacity:1;
        }
```

[image]

I think I am missing something so when hovering nothing happens. I am trying for the last hour but not getting any idea what's wrong with it. Let me know if someone here can help me with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

https://jsfiddle.net/jzevomxL/

[image]

❌

```css
.main-quote:hover .overlayTop {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

✅

```css
.quote-area:hover .overlayTop {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

basically, I chose the parent that has nested the `.overlayTop` and used the logic there.

## Previus Answer

this is happening because `.overlayTop` isn't nested inside `.main-quote`, so maybe this is the bug

so to solving it I used `+` which means select me the next to this hovered element

❌ `.main-quote:hover .overlayTop {}`

✅ `.main-quote:hover+.overlayTop {}`

```css
.quote-area {
  position: relative;
}

.overlayTop {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-quote:hover+.overlayTop {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog_content d-flex flex-column bg-black h-100 text-center pt-3 pb-3 px-3 mx-3">
  <h5>નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની શરૂઆત</h5>
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-center align-items-center mb-0 quote-area">
    <div class="main-quote w-100">
      <p class="">
        નુતન વર્ષ 2023 ની <br /> શરૂઆત કંઈક એવી થાય, <br /> તમારા જીવનમાં ખુશીઓ ફેલાય, <br /> આનંદ મંગલથી દરેક દિવસ <br /> પસાર થાય એવી હાર્દિક <br /> શુભકામનાઓ !!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlayTop">
      <p class="">
        nutan varsh 2023 ni <br /> sharuat kaik evi thay, <br /> tamar jivanam khushio felay, <br /> anand mangalathi darek divas <br /> pasar thay evi hardik <br /> shubhakamanao !!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="time d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center align-items-end mt-auto border-top pt-3">
    <div class="left text-start">
      <h6 class="mb-0">
        <a class="link-bold" href="https://stag.mysite.com/gu/festival/happy-new-year-2023">નવા વરસની શુભકામનાઓ</a
            >
          </h6>
          <p class="mb-0">
            <small>14 hours ago</small>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <a href="https://stag.mysite.com/gu/post/happy-new-year-2023-68400">
            <img
              src="https://stag.mysite.com/assets/images/share.png"
              class="mx-2"
              alt="share quote"
              width="24"
              height="24"
            />
          </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine here but in my site, its still same!

Comment: @Manisha send me the link to your deployed site

Comment: https://stag.quotesdiary.com/gu/latest-gujarati-festival-status/

Comment: @Manisha I tried, is not normal that even a `.main-quote:hover {}` for example don't work in your site. can you give all the code, so I can modify it (not js, just html, css) in a codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: OK sir, Let me try it

Comment: @Manisha but style="" inline css works fine, maybe is some css that disactivate all the other new code. because it should work fine

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ueg8hjxq/

Comment: @Manisha writed the new answer now

Comment: Finally its working fine. Thanks a lot. I have accepted it as well up voted it. Thanks again.